# set limit to pages for scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, limit

I'm scraping https://myanimelist.net/anime.php#/
and you can see there is **genres** section
I want to return as a **csv** only first 18 pages and stop before **explicit genres**
How i can do that? here is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class Link(scrapy.Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()

class LinkListsSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
    name = 'link_lists'
    allowed_domains = ['https://myanimelist.net/']
    start_urls = ['https://myanimelist.net/anime.php#/']

    def parse(self, response):

        xpath = '//a[re:test(@class, "genre-name-link")]/@href'
        selection = response.xpath(xpath)
        for s in selection :
            l = Link()
            l['link'] = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + s.get()
            yield l
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as "setting a limit to pages". You may see "pages" in the list of links, but scrapy doesn't see pages. It sees a giant piece of HTML. Also don't think of scraping as scanning the page the way your eye does. Your job is to use selectors like a knife to carve out the section you want to look at. You use XPath to navigate to and draw the boundaries around that section.

The method I used is to identify the section called **Genres**, then collect all the links under that section only. Since that section is actually the next sibling of the title div (rather than a descendant as you might think by looking at it), I used the `following-sibling` [axis](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), then `[1]` to "go to the next (1) `div` (which contains the 18 Genres) and collect all links from under that."

In other words, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div>Genres</div>
<div class="genre-link">
    -- Anime Genre Links here --
</div>
<div>Explicit Genres</div>
<div class="genre-link">
    -- Explicit Genre Links here --
```

So the way you navigate this is to locate `<div>Genres</div>`, then hop to its following sibling (the next `div`), then look for links inside that.

```py
class LinkListsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'link_lists'
    allowed_domains = ['https://myanimelist.net/']
    start_urls = ['https://myanimelist.net/anime.php#/']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        xpath = '//div[text()="Genres"]/following-sibling::div[@class="genre-link"][1]//a/@href'
        selection = response.xpath(xpath)
        for s in selection:
            l = Link()
            l['link'] = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + s.get()
            yield l
```

Make sure you add `**kwargs` to your parse function arguments btw, so it more accurately matches the base class signature.

Answer (score 0):

Please use @Steven answer. I just want to illustrate how to get the first 18 links from the page using XPath:

```
'(//a[@class="genre-name-link"])[position() <= 18]/@href'
```